# smsManager.sendTextMessage is not working on some phone models

Tags: android, smsmanager

smsManager.sendTextMessage is not working on some smartphone models. But on some other models it is working perfectly. My code is below. "android.permission.SEND_SMS" permission included in manifest file.

```
    try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobileno, null, otp, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Could Not Send OTP. Try On Another Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

I decoded the "Exception" and it shows "uid 10214 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS"

Comment: What language is this even? You can improve on your question views by adding smart tags.

Comment: Please see my modified question.

Comment: Are you handling runtime permission for android 6.0 device

Comment: No. Android version is 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This will fail on devices running API 23 (Marshmallow) or newer due to the newer runtime permissions model.  On those devices you'll need to integrate support for requesting permission from the user.

This talk at Droicon NYC 2015 will help give you more info: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

If you are interested in a helper library to make it easier to work with, check out [Andele](https://github.com/hiqes/andele)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added code for runtime permission and now it is working.